# "df -h ~" thinks my drive is full, but it shouldn't even be half way. Can't install stuff (13.04)

Tags: installation, 13.04, partitioning, ssd, disk-usage

Using a Corsair Force 3 120gb SSD, with 13.04 (no other OS's installed)

df -h ~ reports that I have 94gb available (wut?), and 82gb used (wrong).
GParted says i'm only using a few hundred megabytes (way off)
Disk Usage Analyser says i'm using about 56gb, but also thinks i'm almost full up (wtf)

From searching, I found someone suggest that the trash isn't being emptied properly (i think that was what they said), and that I should do something called "vaccuming" to the drive. No idea how, or what it is, or even if it is actually relevant.

Any input is welcome. I am still very new to ubuntu so this might be some n00b mistake on my part.



df -h ~
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root   94G   82G  8.2G  91% /

Comment: Please post the results of `df -h`, `mount` and `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: And check hidden files in your home directory. I recently had problem with xsession log which took about 30 GiBs (there were Wine errors).

Comment: When asking questions, you need to be as detailed as you can.  Don't just say "df reports blah" actually paste the output into your question.

Comment: Using Disk Space Analyzer, you should be able to see exactly where the space is used. If you provide that kind of details, it'll be much easier to help you.

Comment: disk usage analyser says i'm only using 44.6gb total on my SSD but everything still thinks there's no space

Comment: /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root   94G   89G  429M 100% /

Comment: You appear to be using LVM. GParted does not support that properly as far as I know, because it's multi-layer (physical volume on partition, on top of that a volume group, a logical volume on top of that and a filesystem on top of that). `df` output is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

I ran `gksudo baobab` and found that root/share/trash had 50gb of data.